# Create tex table with list of coefficients

Tags: latex, stata

I want to create a tex table showing the different coefficients of an x variable when regressed on different y variables. My code is as follows:

```
local vars yvar1 yvar2 yvar3 etc. [there are over 100]

foreach var of local vars{    
        reghdfe `var' xvar, vce(cluster i.country) a(i.country)
        scalar `var'_coefficient = _b[xvar]
        
}
```

Therefore, I have a list of scalars which correspond to the coefficients that I want to include in a tex table with the following format:

| Variable | X Coefficient |
| --- | --- |
| yvar1 | 0.5 |
| yvar2 | -0.4 |
| yvar3 | 0.7 |
| ... | ... |

I have tried a few ways of creating a table like this but so far to no avail. I was wondering if anyone has any ideas of how I could create such a table?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you can use the following code. However, does not seem efficient since you'd need to input the variable names into the frmttable command. You can do this automatically with outreg2. However, you would have 100 columns.  There is probably a more efficient way to present your output than a table with 100 roes.

```
bcuse wage2, clear

local vars hours married south sibs meduc lwage
local count = 0

foreach var of local vars {    
        reghdfe `var' lwage, vce(cluster urban) a(urban)
        scalar `var'_coefficient = e(b)[1,1]
        local count = `count' + 1
}


matrix coefficients = J(`count',1,.)


local count = 1

foreach var of local vars {    
    mat coefficients[`count',1] = `var'_coefficient
    local count = `count' + 1 
}


frmttable, statmat(coefficients) sdec(2) rtitle( "var1" \ "var2" \ "var3" \ "var4" \ "var5" \ "var6") ctitle("variables", "coeff.")
```